# save 2 items in db in 1 controller method(rails )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i have a problem with saving 2 items in db at one moment(i am using rails 3.1). I have model Message

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :content
end
```

Message model have params: user_id(reciever), user_from(sender), and content(text)

and model User is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :messages
end
```

in MessagesController i have method

```
 def create
  @message =Message.new(params[:message])


  User.find(@message.user_id).messages.build(params[:message])
  User.find(@message.user_from).messages.build(params[:message])
  end
```

and the problem is that User.find(@message.user_id) only have this message , user_from dont have. I even have tryed this `User.find(2).messages.build(params[:message])` instead of `User.find(@message.user_from).messages.build(params[:message])` and user with id 2 dont have this message too, only user with user_id have. what i am doing wrong??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `create` rather than `build`.

`build` is used when you want to create an model instance but don't want to save it immediately. In your case the message instances are being created but not saved.

Comment: Find and replace the word `build` and replace it with `create`. [You obviously figured this out since you removed the comment].

Comment: thanks. sorry for newbie question) i have removed comment cause it was very stupid question in coment)

Answer (score 1):

Your message model should have association to both sender and receiver of the message,

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender
  belongs_to :receiver
  validates_presence_of :content
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :send_messages, :foreign_key => "message_from"
  has_many :received_messages, :foreign_key => "message_id"
end
```

Also assuming your params will have the message_id(id of message receiver), you should do the following in your controller,

```
@message = current_user.send_messages.build(params[:message])
```

Answer (score 1):

The model design is not right. How about:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
end
```

And the controller is simple (you need params[:message][:sender_id] and params[:message][:receiver_id] to be set from the form):

```
def create
  @message = Message.create(params[:message])
  ...
end
```

But you probably don't want the user to tamper with the sender identity, so:

```
def create
  @message = current_user.sent_messages.create(params[:message])
  ...
end
```