# how to set double params in form (like params[param1][param2])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i know that it is newbie question but i dont know the answer(

i need to set in my form params[:message][:reciever_id] how todo it?

my user model have

```
 has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
 has_many :received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
```

i was doing in my message form

```
 = f.hidden_field :receiver_id,:value => @user
 = f.hidden_field :sender_id, :value => current_user
```

but it doesnt work. So how to do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
= f.hidden_field :receiver_id, :value => @user.id
= f.hidden_field :sender_id, :value => current_user.id
```

But that's not the way to do it, prefill the value in your controller (action new):

```
@message = Message.new(:receiver => receiver_user)
```

And in the create action:

```
@message = current_user.sent_messages.create(params[:message])
```

Comment: it writes "unknown attribute: receiver_id"

Comment: maybe i need to generate some additional params in database?

Comment: aren't you using the message model I proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944941/save-2-items-in-db-in-1-controller-methodrails? (of course, with integer attributes sender_id, receiver_id in the schema)

Comment: i am using your message model at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944941/save-2-items-in-db-in-1-controller-methodrails

Comment: my message model have 'belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => "User" '

Comment: ahhh, sorry. i had an error in word "receiver" in database. now it works with your example!

Comment: how can i do in new action @message = Message.new(:receiver => @user)?